# Creating Simultaneous equations from word problems

Tags: word-problem

I can't seem to figure out how to take word problems and convert them into a solvable simultaneous equation.

A rectangle has an area of 66.49metres^2. The width of the rectangle is 6.75 metres shorter than the length.

(1)Form a quadratic equation to represent this information.

(2)Use this equation to find both the length and the width of the rectangle

So far the only thing i'm getting is that the   width = length-6.75, so W=L-6.75

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

Let $L $ be the length.

the width will be $l=L-6.75$.

the area is then

$L (L-6.75)=66.49$.

Comment: How would one solve that then?

Comment: with discriminant delta.